# unexpected identifier error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I couldn't catch what's wrong with my code.

This block of logic should be ok

```
const r = x.map(obj => {
  if (obj.hour <= 10 || obj.hour >= 22) {
    return obj
  }
})

console.log(r)
```

but the error is somewhere. https://jsfiddle.net/her7uzps/

I tried to lint the json, it's fine too. I tried to create an index.html instead of using jsfiddle, it still can't show which line has problem.

Comment: what do you expect with map? could filter be the better choice?

Comment: Your data has a typo in the fiddle: `cosnt x`.

Comment: Pleas check your fiddle. It need to be `const x`

Comment: did already you debug?

Answer (score 3):

You error is not there. You error is at the begining of the code, where you wrote `cosnt` and you should put `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You are misspell the word `const` on declaring the array .And do with `Array#filter` instead `map` its easy to reconstruct the array with condition

```js
const x = [{
  "hour": 0,
  "total_count": 0,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 1,
  "total_count": 0,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 2,
  "total_count": 0,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 3,
  "total_count": 0,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 4,
  "total_count": 0,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 5,
  "total_count": 0,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 6,
  "total_count": 0,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 7,
  "total_count": 1,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 1
}, {
  "hour": 8,
  "total_count": 21,
  "male_count": 3,
  "female_count": 18
}, {
  "hour": 9,
  "total_count": 230,
  "male_count": 110,
  "female_count": 120
}, {
  "hour": 10,
  "total_count": 308,
  "male_count": 151,
  "female_count": 157
}, {
  "hour": 11,
  "total_count": 238,
  "male_count": 103,
  "female_count": 135
}, {
  "hour": 12,
  "total_count": 236,
  "male_count": 128,
  "female_count": 108
}, {
  "hour": 13,
  "total_count": 237,
  "male_count": 153,
  "female_count": 84
}, {
  "hour": 14,
  "total_count": 234,
  "male_count": 130,
  "female_count": 104
}, {
  "hour": 15,
  "total_count": 180,
  "male_count": 99,
  "female_count": 81
}, {
  "hour": 16,
  "total_count": 203,
  "male_count": 117,
  "female_count": 86
}, {
  "hour": 17,
  "total_count": 235,
  "male_count": 139,
  "female_count": 96
}, {
  "hour": 18,
  "total_count": 194,
  "male_count": 111,
  "female_count": 83
}, {
  "hour": 19,
  "total_count": 149,
  "male_count": 89,
  "female_count": 60
}, {
  "hour": 20,
  "total_count": 38,
  "male_count": 20,
  "female_count": 18
}, {
  "hour": 21,
  "total_count": 1,
  "male_count": 1,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 22,
  "total_count": 1,
  "male_count": 1,
  "female_count": 0
}, {
  "hour": 23,
  "total_count": 0,
  "male_count": 0,
  "female_count": 0
}]

const r = x.filter(obj => (obj.hour <= 10 || obj.hour >= 22) )

console.log(r)
```